# data from jsonp

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

¿How i do (with Jquery) to obtain a specific value from this json result? for example for email

```
 [
 {
   address: "",
   province: "",
   firstName: "Anna",
   email: "anna@example.org",
   postalCode: "",
   key: "135",
   type: "technical",
   description: "",
   isPrimaryContact: true,
   phone: "",
   country: "",
   city: "",
   salutation: "",
   position: " Projects Leader, Academic Systems",
   lastName: ""
 }
]
```

I use $.ajax() , from a json in a different server.

Comment: This is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a JSON object, you would simply use:

```
var email = data.email;
```

Here is a full, shortened example:

```
 var data = {
   address: "",
   province: "",
   firstName: "Anna",
   email: "anna@example.org"
 };

alert(data.email);
```

If your data is really an array, you would need to use:

```
alert(data[0].email);
```

Similar shortened example:

```
 var data = [{
   address: "",
   province: "",
   firstName: "Anna",
   email: "anna@example.org"
 }];

alert(data[0].email);
```

Comment: In OP's case, it'd be `data[0].email`.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the `[]` was coming from some console output, or was part of the actual data - so I gave both possibilities. To be valid JSON, an array should be within the JSON object, not surrounding it.